# getting error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, python-3.x

getting this error,

**'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'**

how to solve this problem

**views.py**

```
def profile_update_view(request, username):
    user = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username)
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if form.is_valid():
                created_prof = form.save(commit=False)
                created_prof.user = request.user
                created_prof.save()

                return redirect('profiles:profile-detail',username=username)

        return render(request, "profiles/profile_form.html", {
            "username": username,
            "form": form,
        })
```

Answer (score 5):

`filter` always returns a queryset. You should use `get` to get a single instance.

```
user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
```